# Excute program from anywhere in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I downloaded the executable NGROK.  It is currently in the /Application folder.

Path /application/ngrok

I would love to be able execute the program from anywhere in the terminal.  What is the best way to do this?  Should I create some type of link or move it somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alias. Type in `editalias` into Terminal and then add after the other aliases: `alias ngrok="~/Applications/ngrok"`. Then you can type `ngrok` wherever in Terminal you are and it will launch ngrok.

Comment: This is the idea, but editalias is not a command that work in my terminal for OS X

Comment: Then use `nano ~/.bash_profile` instead of `editalias`.

Answer (score 0):

Use ./application/ngrok

The ./path is used to launch executables